# Firebase Auth FACEBOOK_PROVIDER no callback

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to implement the firebase login with firebase-auth (com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.4). 
Google and Email is working fine. But With Facebook I receive the following exception after the Facebook intent returns. The onActivityResult() method is also not called for Facebook.

> org.json.JSONException: No value for email at
>   org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389) at
>   org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550) at
>   com.firebase.ui.auth.provider.FacebookProvider$1.onCompleted(FacebookProvider.java:111)
>   at com.facebook.GraphRequest$1.onCompleted(GraphRequest.java:304) at
>   com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1379) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

```
 startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setProviders(
                                    AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                    AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER,
                                    AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER)

                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Any advice and suggestions will be appreciated.